# Building with a linked file in WIX

Tags: msbuild, wix

I’ve a project targeting wix 3.7, using VS2013 with a VSO repository.  When I add files to a project using “Add As Link”, the build fails with “cannot find the file”. E.g. in the wxs file, I have:

```
<Icon Id="ArpIcon" SourceFile="Images\favicon.ico"/>
```

The source file is in a folder outside of the project, and is already checked into VSO.  When I build, the error in the Output includes:

> … error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file
>   'Images\favicon.ico'.

If the file is included directly (i.e. not as a link), then no problem.

[Wix Tips & Tricks](http://www.kentie.net/article/wixtipstricks/) seems to suggest wix understands linked files.  Any ideas on what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured out that if I also change the SourceFile attribute to the *real* file location rather than where the link appears in the project structure, then it will build. So, with the wixproj line reading as

```
<Content Include="..\..\_Cobranded Common\Images\favicon.ico">
  <Link>Images\favicon.ico</Link>
</Content>
```

and matching the wxs line to it as

```
<Icon Id="ArpIcon" SourceFile="..\..\_Cobranded Common\Images\favicon.ico"/>
```

it now builds.

Would be interested to hear if there's a simpler or more intuitive solution.